# Unsourced notice - how to add one?

Tags: support, moderation

Today I have seen a notice "Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.":

[image]

for the first time. What do I need to do to make it appear on deserving posts? And what do I need to do to get the notice acted upon, deleting unsourced garbage?

Source: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/98781/4188

Answer (score 3):

It's a mod only post notice - we can add it on posts (as one of my fellow mods amusingly seems to have done on this question above ;)).  If you feel one deserves it, flag for us. Downvote and comment as well (the normal user's version of the post).  Hell you could even copy and paste the text from that post above :)

Comment: I flagged a number of posts a week or two ago and I believe those did not get this notice. Is is a new one?

Comment: @chx it'd be then up to the mod who reviews the flags to decide if it's worth adding the post notice.  It's not an automatic process.

Answer (score 2):

Flag the offending post and ask the mods to add a notice. Regular users cannot do it on their own.